# Cannot add FK using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` with `Entity Framework` and I'm trying to add an `FK` in my `UserDetails` table. These are the model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetails UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetails
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Uri FacebookLink { get; set; }
    public Uri TwitterLink { get; set; }
    public Uri SkypeLink { get; set; }

    public virtual User UserKey { get; set; }
}
```

The table `User` is the `Master` table which contains all the registered user in my application (I'm using AspNetCore.Identity).

Actual I want add as `FK` the property `UserId` which must bound the `Id` of `User`. So inside the `ApplicationContext` class I did the following:

```
public class DemoAppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public DemoAppContext(DbContextOptions<DemoAppContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.Entity<UserDetails>(entity =>
       {
           entity.Property(e => e.Biography).HasMaxLength(150);

           entity.Property(e => e.Country).HasMaxLength(10);

           entity.HasOne(d => d.UserKey)
                 .WithOne(p => p.UserDetail)
                 .HasForeignKey(d => d.???; <- problem here
       });
   }

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I overrided the `OnModelCreating` and using the `ModelBuilder` I defined for `UserDetails` table the `MaxLength` of some properties. In the last line of `builder.Entity<UserDetails>` I tried to assign the `FK` creating the relationship with `HasOne => UserKey` which contains the object `User`. The relationship is `1 to 1` so I used `WithOne` and assigned `UserDetail` which contains the `UserDetails` object.

At the end I used `HasForeignKey` but when I type `d.` the compiler doesn't show any properties.

What I did wrong? Maybe I overcomplicated the things?

Sorry for any errors, and thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: If you are using EF core, please change your tag to it. EF is different in many ways to EF core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will work:

```
builder.Entity<UserDetails>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Biography).HasMaxLength(150);
    entity.Property(e => e.Country).HasMaxLength(10);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.UserKey)
              .WithOne(p => p.UserDetail)
          .HasForeignKey<UserDetails>(x => x.UserId);  //???; < -problem here
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works, could you tell me which command should I execute in console for update the database tables?

Comment: @Charanoglu   I usually use  `dotnet ef migrations add xxx` + `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: @Charanoglu By the way , I find that the type of your `UserDetails.UserId` is `string` while the type of  `User.Id` is `int` .  It might not work as you expected .

Comment: I get a different error `No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Uri'.`

Comment: @Charanoglu , I found the same issue when I tested my own code before . I thought you used EF that can deal with it (I used EF Core). So I just changed the `Uri` to `string` .

Comment: Ok I launched the command `add-migration <migration name> -context <context name>` and `update-database` but actually in the explore object I cannot see my new table `UserDetails` Is displayed this message: `To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated`

Comment: @Charanoglu That's typically because you are changing a type of a column to another type, while the column has been referenced by another column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179999/discussion-between-charanoglu-and-itminus).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
        entity.HasOne(d => d.UserKey)
                      .WithOne(p => p.UserDetail)
                      .HasForeignKey<User>(b => b.Id);
```

or

```
public class UserDetails
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserKey))]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Uri FacebookLink { get; set; }
    public Uri TwitterLink { get; set; }
    public Uri SkypeLink { get; set; }

    public virtual User UserKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But with your solution I cannot define the other properties?

Comment: How is your properties you want to create? I don't change your entity

Comment: The problem is that in my `ModelBuilder` there is no `HasRequired`

Comment: ah, you are using EF Core, can you check my edited post?