# EF 2.1 incorrectly translating Group By Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a query working on EF 2.1 against an existing database.  I'm getting an error which suggests that I haven't configured my models properly.

My models:

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
}

public class JobStatus
{

    [Key]
    public string JobStatusId { get; set; }

    public string Colour { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

}
```

My Query:

```
var jobs = _context.Jobs
        .GroupBy(p => p.JobStatus.Colour)
        .Select(g => new { colour = g.Key, count = g.Count() });
```

The error is "Invalid column name 'JobStatusId'.  EF is translating into the following query:

```
SELECT [p.JobStatus].[Colour] AS [colour], COUNT(*) AS [count]
  FROM [Jobs] AS [p]
  LEFT JOIN [JobStatus] AS [p.JobStatus] ON [p].[JobStatusId] = [p.JobStatus].[JobStatusId]
  GROUP BY [p.JobStatus].[Colour]
```

Which isn't right.  p.JobStatusId doesn't exist, it should be p.JobStatus.JobStatusId.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've added this to my Job model;

```
public string JobStatusFK {get; set;}
```

And tried the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasOne(x=>x.JobStatus).HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorFK);
```

However Intellisense doesn't allow this:

```
'ReferenceNavigationBuilder<Job, JobStatus>' does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey' and no accessible extension method 'HasForeignKey' accepting a first argument of type 'ReferenceNavigationBuilder<Job, JobStatus>' could be found
```

Comment: Can you declare `public string JobStatusId { get; set; }` in the `Job` class

Comment: But I don't want that field in the Job Class....

Comment: Then you use `HasForeignKey` in fluent API

Comment: you follow `Database-First` or `Code-First`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that was an FK

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: @RobbieMills I'm not sure why the `public string JobStatusFK {get; set;}` doesn't work . But the reason why Intellisense does not work can be solved by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310518/cannot-add-fk-using-entityframework/52311598#52311598

Answer (score 1):

That's because the relatinship of your `Job : JobStatus` is `Many-to-One`.

The EF thought there's a foreign key that references `JobStatus` , i.e. , a `JobStatusId` column within the `Job`set as `FK` .

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, what's the best way to fix this?  It's a model that I'm using in an asp.net 5 app which works well there

Comment: @RobbieMills  I saw the comments by @vivek nuna . In my opinion , a foreign key will make sense .  Could you tell us why you don't want a column of `Job.JobStatusId` but have a `JobStatus` navigation property at the same time ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that was a FK

Comment: @RobbieMills - What you are running into is one of the primary reasons you should never use your data model in your view.  Your data model and your view model are different concerns, and often require different definitions.  You can solve this by using your fully populated data model (that represents your database) and projecting into a view model which does not contain the data you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that `JobStatusId` is FK in `Job` class.

You can use the below declaration in the `Job` class or use the `HasForeignKey` in DBContext class using fluent API.

```
public string JobStatusId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I've tried this, same error, after some more reading, I added code which I've described in my Update, but still can't get this to work